# Xamarin.iOS iOS 8 UITableView custom cell height does not change

Tags: uitableview, xamarin, ios8, xamarin.ios

I am trying to create a `UITableCell` that grows based on their content like [this recipe](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/autosizing-row-height/).

I have added all required parts as per recipe but I don't know what went wrong. Here is [My Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iz52uytxb8wv9lo/Archive.zip?dl=0).

My custom table cell height is not changing and it remaining at the default height.

FYI: Min iOS support 8.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the table to grow you need to have a chain of autolayout constraints from top to bottom.

You are missing the constraint that links the top label with the bottom label:

[image]

If you add that it will then look like so:

[image]

Seeing as you uploaded the code, [Here is your code with the updated constraint](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4361929/Archive%202.zip)

Comment: tnx for your efforts those.